# Removing Noise From an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I'm using Geometric mean filter to remove noise instead of median filter as image quality goes off in former case. code shown below is a part of m-file to remove noise.

```
fname = getappdata(0, 'fname');
[a, map] = imread(fname);
x = ind2rgb(a, map);
b = im2double(x);
w=fspecial('gaussian',[3,3]);
geom=exp(imfilter(log(b),ones(3,3),'replicate')).^(1/3/3);
fname=imfilter(b,w,'replicate');
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(fname);
```

If i press push button which is named 'Remove Noise' above code get executed irrespective of image quality/property. In the sense even if no noise is present, image will be subjected to filter.

My question, is there any way to detect whether noise is present or not, so that the moment i pressed push button if no Noise in image it should display a message stating 'NO NOISE TO REMOVE' automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to determine whether an image is noisy or not.

However, you can compare resulting image `fname` with the input image `b` in such a way that if their difference is lower than a certain threshold, then it can be decided that denoising operation has not changed image effectively and there is not much noise in the original image like:

```
threshold_ratio = 0.2; % to be decided experimentally

difference_ratio = sum(sum((fname - b).^2)) / sum(sum(b.^2));

if difference_ratio < threshold_ratio

   disp('NO NOISE TO REMOVE');

end
```